# Change array in next click in winforms application

Tags: c#

I have three arrays:

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 };
int[] arr2 = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 };
int[] arr3 = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 };
```

How i can change array in next button click? In first click i want use `arr1` in second `arr2` etc.

Comment: please show the code for the windows form.

Comment: Just keep count of clicks and work with a switch

Comment: Use `list<int[]>` to keep track of which array you use..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have an event handler already.

```
private void btnClick (object sender, EventArgs e) {

}
```

What you should do is to keep track of the click count. You usually do this by creating a variable. So let's do that.

```
private int clickCount = 0; //Please put this outside the event handler
```

Now for each click, you are going to increase the variable by 1

```
clickCount++;
```

Then, check if the click count is one or two:

```
if (clickCount == 1) {
    //do stuff with arr1
} else if (clickCount == 2) {
    //do stuff with arr2
}
```

That's how easy it is!

You might want to reset the count to 1 after the user clicks it twice so

```
if (clickCount == 1) {
    //do stuff with arr1
} else if (clickCount == 2) {
    //do stuff with arr2
    clickCount = 1;
}
```